# Deploying BAPP Migrated to PHP8 on Windows Server 2012 with Apache while Maintaining PHP5 Compatibility for AAPP and CAPP

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, php-5.5, php-8.2

I have three PHP (PHP5) applications, E:/dude/web/AAPP, E:/dude/web/BAPP, and E:/dude/web/CAPP, that are all running on Apache on Windows Server 2012.

How can I deploy BAPP, which was originally developed for PHP5, after migrating it to PHP8 on a Windows Server 2012 environment that uses Apache as the web server? Additionally, I want to ensure that AAPP and CAPP, which currently work with PHP5, continue to function without any issues.

This is the content of my httpd.conf file. I have not yet started the configuration of PHP8 for my application BAPP:

```
LoadModule php5_module E:/dude/bin/script/php5apache2_4.dll
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir E:/dude/bin/script/

<Directory "E:/dude/web/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

I have already downloaded PHP 8.2.7 and renamed it as "php8_2". I then placed it in the directory "E:/dude/bin/script/php8_2/". what is the next step ?

I have tried the following:

in the httpd.conf i add this lines:

```
#php8 config
<IfModule php8_module>
    LoadModule php8_module E:/dude/bin/script/php8_2/php8apache2_4.dll
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php8 .php
    PHPIniDir E:/dude/bin/script/php8_2/
</IfModule>
```

However, I'm unsure if these steps are sufficient for the desired configuration.